# Sympy eigenvals of Matrix with variable

Tags: python, sympy

I use in Python Sympy to calculate the eigenvalues (e.g) of a Matrix A with variables. Has anyone an idea how I can calculate the eigenvals of such Matrix? The command A.eigenvals() doesn't work. For example the follwing code:

```
x = symbols("x")
A = Array([[x, x], [x, x]])
A.eigenvals()
AttributeError: 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'eigenvals'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Matrix` rather than `Array`:

```
In [6]: Matrix([[x, x], [x, x]]).eigenvals()                                                                                                   
Out[6]: {0: 1, 2⋅x: 1}
```